# Best practice for connecting to an API using OAuth2 in a UI-less (backend-only) app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, backend, quickbooks

I want to have a scheduled job that connects to Quickbooks Online at the end of each day to inject invoices.

This is my first time dealing with OAuth.

Since my app doesn't have a UI, I used Postman to generate an authorization code from my Client ID and Client Secret. However, I only have 5 minutes to insert it in my project and request an access token for it. If I do it quick enough, I do get an access token and it all works fine from there.

Since my scheduled job will run each night, I can refresh the access token using the refresh token which is good for 100 days. As long as it runs at least once every 100 days, I should be good (not really worried about that part).

But I'm wondering how to manage the initial setup process when I'll be deploying to new environments? It doesn't make sense to request the authorization code manually and save it to a database (or Redis) immediately when the project is deployed in a new environment, and then quickly run the script that is responsible for getting the first access token.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [client credential grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4), which is typically used for machine-to-machine authentication where a specific user's permission to access data is not required. You will need to register your job as a [confidential client](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-2.1) and the rest is straightforward. Your job will [authenticate itself](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-3.2.1) to the authorization server and obtain an `access_token`, there is no need to use a `refresh_token`, your job/app/script/server can simply obtain a new token every time using its `client_id` and `client_secret`.

You can use the following sample curl request to get an access token:

```
curl -X POST "https://authorization-server.com/oauth/token" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     -u "CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET" \
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
     -d "scope=your_scope"
```

After making the request, you will receive a JSON response containing the access token:

```json
{
  "access_token": "your_access_token",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I wasn't aware of the existance of client credential grant, which seems to be exactly what I would need. However, it seems that Quickbooks didn't implement them (countless discussions on their forums).